# how to find predefined timezone IDs of ballerina time package?

Tags: datetime, ballerina

In ballerina time packages **createTime** function, it asks for zoneID as a function parameter, when I provide a custom zoneID, program keeps running without any output. Is there a way to find those predefined time zoneIDs with relevant timezones?

Comment: From https://ballerina.io/learn/api-docs/ballerina/time.html#createTime it looks like the same as from Java/Oracle ZoneId https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html, which gets the long form of Zones from the "IANA Time Zone Database (TZDB)"

Comment: As @jdv suggested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Answer (score 1):

The underlying implementation of ballerina time package is Java and the zone ID processing rules are similar to the Java rules. Basically rules are as follows.

- If the zone ID equals 'Z', the result is UTC. If the zone ID equals
  'GMT', 'UTC' or 'UT', it is equivalent to UTC.
- If the zone ID starts with '+' or '-', the ID is parsed as an offset.
  Offset can be specified in one of the following ways.

  +h,
  +hh,
  +hh:mm,
  -hh:mm,
  +hhmm,
  -hhmm,
  +hh:mm:ss,
  -hh:mm:ss,
  +hhmmss,
  -hhmmss
- Also zone id can be a region-based zone ID. The format is '{area}/{city}' eg: "America/Panama". The zones are based on IANA  Time Zone Database (TZDB) supplied data.

Ex:

Using UTC

```
time:Timezone zoneValue = {zoneId:"Z"};
time:Time time = new(1456876583555, zoneValue);
```

Using offset

```
time:Timezone zoneValue = {zoneId:"-05:00"};
time:Time time = new(1456876583555, zoneValue);
```

Using region-based zone ID

```
time:Timezone zoneValue = {zoneId:"America/Panama"};
time:Time time = new(1456876583555, zoneValue);
```

We hope to improve this API in a future version of Ballerina with proper representation for the zone ids etc.

You can refer to the [Ballerina date time example](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/date-time.html) for more details.

Comment: It is better if you could update the time package documentation by adding more details on timezones. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and we have created an issue to track this. https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/9586